# Is there a JavaScript equivalent to numpy.linalg.pinv?

Tags: javascript, numpy

I'm trying to solve a linear system of equations that is overdetermined (Ax = B) given a matrix A generated by user input on a website with Javascript. In python I could just use numpy.linalg.pinv(A) to find the pseudoinverse of A and multiply that pseudo inverse with B to solve the system -- is there a JavaScript equivalent (library and/or piece of code) that could do this?

I tried using math.js; although it doesn't seem to have a pseudo inverse function, it has other matrix operations. I tried using

`math.multiply(math.inv(math.multiply(math.transpose(A), A)), math.transpose(A))`

to find the pseudo inverse but the matrix I got from multiplying the transpose of A with A was not invertible because the columns of A are apparently linearly dependent (I'm not very experienced with linear algebra but that's what I've gathered from some research online). However, numpy can still find a pseudo inverse even when the matrix A has linearly dependent columns (I tested the system with numpy) so that brings me back to the question of whether there's a way to replicate numpy's pseudo inverse function. And if not, is there some other solution to this problem?

Comment: Asking for a library or other off-site resource is off-topic (Help Center -> [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). You might want to rephrase your question and add a [mcve] using math.js (or some other library you've found)

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been some time since this question was asked, but there are a few libraries for doing linear algebra in JS available now (2021), which I'll leave here for reference:

- [ml-matrix](https://github.com/mljs/matrix)
- [eigen](https://github.com/BertrandBev/eigen-js)
- [linear-algebra-js](https://github.com/rohan-sawhney/linear-algebra-js)
- [emlapack](https://github.com/likr/emlapack)
- [linalg.js](https://enkimute.github.io/linalg.js/)

Just to name a few. From your question it seems like you are trying to solve a least squares estimator:
[image]

If this is the case, most (all?) of the above libraries provide more robust / performant solutions compared to computing the pseudo-inverse, namely using LU/QR/SVD decompositions:

```js
// Using ml-matrix
const { Matrix, solve } = require('ml-matrix');
var X = new Matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]);
var y = Matrix.columnVector([8, 20, 32]);
var b = solve(X, y, (useSVD = true));

// Using linear algebra js
const { SparseMatrix, DenseMatrix } = require('linear-algebra');
// solve the linear system Ax = b, where A is a square sparse matrix
var X = SparseMatrix.identity(5, 5);
var y = DenseMatrix.ones(5, 1);

var lu = X.lu();
var b = lu.solveSquare(y);
```

However, if you *really* require calculating the pseudo-inverse, ml-matrix is the only library which supports this (as far as I know). In principle, Eigen supports this as well, but I haven't seen any JS port actually exposing this functionality yet.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q :** *And if not, is there some other solution to this problem?*

Yes, there is a way.

Implement distributed-processing workflow. Let JavaScript do its part and let **`numpy`** side do the work it is so smart at. Similar concept is common for many use-cases, where specialised tools solve parts of the problem and some workflow integration mediator "glues" the distributed parts together.

So, make JavaScript part equipped with ZeroMQ/**`zmq`** or **`nanomsg`**, communicate the **`A, B`** over the interconnect to a python-side, there numpy will make its best for the smart, vectorised number-crunching, and let the received results pass back to whatever next stage of the processing workflow.

ZeroMQ has for years smart tooling for very fast and efficient protocol-less `{ ipc:// | vmci:// }` localhost interconnects, plus has similarly smart, yet non-local protocols for `{ tcp:// | udp:// | ... }` datacentre interconnects, if your localhost resources would become prohibitively small for larger matrix sizes.

There are similar tools ready from **`nanomsg`**, yet you have to check for availability of JavaScript-side usable ports / wrappers.

The rest is just about squeezing out the maximum performance for any given volume of data and a requested cadence of the front-end / back-end transactions running.

Having used this architecture for a turn-around-time under `~ 80 [ms]` just your imagination is your limit. Having also done some **multi-`TB`** linear algebra processing as fast as possible, more care will be necessary there, but the performance-motivated principles are the same.